# How can I compare numbers in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, numeric

I'm unable to get numeric comparisons working:

```sh
echo "enter two numbers";
read a b;

echo "a=$a";
echo "b=$b";

if [ $a \> $b ];
then
    echo "a is greater than b";
else
    echo "b is greater than a";
fi;
```

The problem is that it compares the number from the first digit on, i.e., 9 is bigger than 10, but 1 is greater than 09.

How can I convert the numbers into a type to do a true comparison?

Comment: BTW, in bash a semi-colon is a statement separator, not a statement terminator, which is a new-line.  So if you only have one statement on a line then the `;` at end-of-line are superfluous.  Not doing any harm, just a waste of keystrokes (unless you *enjoy* typing semi-colons).

Comment: To force numbers with leading zeros into decimals: `10#$number` so `number=09; echo "$((10#$number))"` will output `9` while `echo $((number))` will produce a "value too great for base" error.

Comment: The answers all tell you what's right, but not what's wrong: what the `>` operator does in the `[` command is to compare the order two strings should sort in, rather than the order they would sort in as numbers. You can find more info in `man test`.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278707/6993

Answer (score 1411, accepted):

In Bash, you should do your check in an [arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression):

```
if (( a > b )); then
    ...
fi
```

For POSIX shells that don't support `(())`, you can use `-lt` and `-gt`.

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

You can get a full list of comparison operators with `help test` or `man test`.

Comment: As said by @jordanm `"$a" -gt "$b"` is the right answer. Here is a good list of test operator: [Test Constructs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Comment: That is definitely working but I'm still getting "((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")" if I compare 1 and 09 but not 01 and 09 which is odd, but that has basically solved my problem so thanks!

Comment: @advert2013 you shouldn't prefix numbers with zeros. zero-prefixed numbers are octal in bash

Comment: Ah ok, that solves that mystery then - I don't really have any use for zero prefixed numbers but it is nice to know where errors are coming from

Comment: Beware that `test` is a program as is `[`. So `help test` gives information about that. To find out what the built-ins (`[[` and `((`) do you should use `help bash` and navigate to that part.

Comment: If your numbers are really large depending on your system, you may need to switch to bc for comparisons as well. E.g. `function lg_int_less_than() { 
echo "if(${1}<${2}){print 1}else{print 0}"|bc;   
}
`

Comment: Another reference for arithmetic expressions: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

Comment: What about else if statement in arithmetic context

Comment: Arithmetic expressions are great, but operands are treated as [expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482577/bash-arithmetic-expansion-seems-to-be-prone-to-injection-attacks).

Comment: In bash, you should do your check in conditional expressions. `((` is synonymous to `let` which sounds like it was meant for evaluation rather than comparison. Comparison operators of `let` were most likely just side features.

Comment: I have `NUMBER=0.0; while [ "$NUMBER" -lt "1.0" ]; do` and it says `bash: [: 0.0: integer expression expected`

Comment: @AaronFranke math in bash only works with integers, it doesn't do floating point or decimals.

Comment: @JefferyThomas Thanks for the link. However, it's confusing because in this answer, the variable and number (used with double parens) isn't in quotes, while in the list your link refers to, they are. Which one is correct or are they equivalent?

Comment: @not2savvy Don't use quotes in the if conditional. See the Arithmetic Commands section of the linked page for an example. There are different modes of the ArithmeticExpression the example in Arithmetic Expansion uses `test "$(( expression ))"` instead of just `(( expression ))`.

Comment: @JefferyThomas I’m afraid, now I‘m completely confused. You say _Don‘t use quotes_, but I‘m seeing quotes in list as well as the examples you refer to on the page you link to in your first comment.

Comment: @not2savvy If you are ever in doubt, just quote it.

Comment: @not2savvy It depends on how you use it. `if "(( a > b ))"; then …; fi` will not work.

Comment: if we are comparing it with 0, should we do "0" or 0 after `-gt`?

Comment: ((: 0.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard Bash can not handle floating point numbers without the help of an external tool. see this answer below for dealing with floats https://stackoverflow.com/a/49412454/1032785

Comment: do I need the quotes around the variables $a and $b?

Comment: @svebert it's good practice to always quote them, but if they always contain integers it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Remember to make sure that the spaces are not non breaking spaces! Can be a pain to understand and debug, it'll try to run it as a function.

Answer (score 341):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2462620
b=2462620

if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]; then
  echo "They're equal";
fi
```

Integers can be compared with these operators:

```
-eq # Equal
-ne # Not equal
-lt # Less than
-le # Less than or equal
-gt # Greater than
-ge # Greater than or equal
```

See [this cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash#conditionals).

Comment: I just undid your other change - the double quotes around `"$a"` and `"$b"` aren't strictly necessary but they are good practice. Curly braces don't do anything useful here.

Comment: great cheatsheet that you linked, didn't find it before - now bash doesn't seem so magic and unpredictable anymore - thank you!

Comment: are the quotes `"` mandatory or is just `[ $a -eq $b ]` also fine?

Comment: @derHugo quotes are optional. Gilles has a better explanation on when to use them https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/50394

Comment: [Main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668580/4561887) + this answer = perfect

Comment: You don't need quotes if you use double brackets: `if [[ $a -eq $b ]];then`

Comment: plain and simple doesn't work in homebrew bash version 5.0.7.

Comment: You don't need `$` either. Just write `if [[ a -eq b ]]; then`.

Answer (score 62):

There is also one nice thing some people might not know about:

```
echo $(( a < b ? a : b ))
```

This code will print the smallest number out of `a` and `b`

Comment: That's not true. It would also print `b` if `a == b`.

Comment: @konsolebox is it just me, or the smallest number out of 5 and 5 is 5?

Comment: Your statement is ambiguous. Even applying on a command like this won't do: `echo "The smaller number is $(( a < b ? a : b ))."`

Comment: What he's saying is that `a < b` is still true if `a == b`. I don't know all of the vagaries of Bash's conditionals, but there are almost certainly situations where this would make a difference.

Comment: @bikemule No, he's not saying that. If `a == b`, then `a < b` evaluates to false, which is why it would print `b`.

Comment: What is the explanation (incl. references)? Is the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) [built in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Bash), etc.?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, it's about using ternary operator in bash [Arithmetic Expressions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) ([see this](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) also). Feel free to adjust the answer to include the links that you find helpful.

Comment: That's called a ternary. If the 1st condition is true, the 2nd is returned, otherwise the 3rd.

Answer (score 46):

In Bash I prefer doing this as it addresses itself more as a conditional operation unlike using `(( ))` which is more of arithmetic.

```
[[ n -gt m ]]
```

Unless I do complex stuff like

```
(( (n + 1) > m ))
```

But everyone just has their own preferences. Sad thing is that some people impose their unofficial standards.

You can also do this:

```
[[ 'n + 1' -gt m ]]
```

Which allows you to add something else which you could do with `[[ ]]` besides arithmetic stuff.

Comment: This seems to imply that `[[ ]]` forces an arithmetic context like `(( ))`, where `N` gets treated as if it were `$N`, but I don't think that's correct. Or, if that wasn't the intention, the usage of `N` and `M` is confusing.

Comment: @BenjaminW.This would require confirmation from Chet but -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, and -ge are forms of "arithmetic tests" (documented) which could imply that the operands are subject to arithmetic expressions as well..

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this, as you're completely right and [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) clearly states it: "When used with the `[[` command, *`Arg1`* and *`Arg2`* are evaluated as arithmetic expressions [...]".

Comment: I have `NUMBER=0.0; while [[ "$NUMBER" -lt "1.0" ]]; do` and it says `bash: [[: 0.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")`

Comment: @AaronFranke Bash arithmetic doesn't support decimals.

Answer (score 16):

One-line solution.

```
a=2
b=1
[[ ${a} -gt ${b} ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

gt reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

&& reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html

[[...]] construct reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b

${} reference: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 (2.6.2)

> The format for parameter expansion is as follows:
>
> ${expression}
>
> where expression consists of all characters until the matching '}'.
> Any '}' escaped by a  or within a quoted string, and
> characters in embedded arithmetic expansions, command substitutions,
> and variable expansions, shall not be examined in determining the
> matching '}'.
>
> The simplest form for parameter expansion is:
>
> ${parameter}

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Is it a way to implement the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70543262/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 12):

The bracket stuff (e.g., `[[ $a -gt $b ]]` or `(( $a > $b ))` ) isn't enough if you want to use float numbers as well; it would report a syntax error. If you want to compare float numbers or float number to integer, you can use `(( $(bc <<< "...") ))`.

For example,

```
a=2.00
b=1

if (( $(bc <<<"$a > $b") )); then 
    echo "a is greater than b"
else
    echo "a is not greater than b"
fi
```

You can include more than one comparison in the if statement. For example,

```
a=2.
b=1
c=1.0000

if (( $(bc <<<"$b == $c && $b < $a") )); then 
    echo "b is equal to c but less than a"
else
    echo "b is either not equal to c and/or not less than a"
fi
```

That's helpful if you want to check if a numeric variable (integer or not) is within a numeric range.

Comment: This does not work for me. As far as I can tell, the bc command does not return an exit value but instead prints "1" if the comparison is true (and "0" otherwise). I have to write this instead: `if [ "$(bc <<<"$a > $b") == "1" ]; then echo "a is greater than b; fi`

Comment: @TerjeMikal For your command, do you mean `if [ $(bc <<<"$a > $b") == "1" ]; then echo "a is greater than b"; fi`? (I think your command was mis-written.) If so, that works, too. The Bash Calculator (bc) command is a basic calculator command. Some more usage examples found [here](https://www.tutorialsandyou.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-bc-18.html) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bc-command-linux-examples/). I don't know why my example command didn't work for you though.

Answer (score 8):

This code can also compare floats. It is using AWK (it is not pure Bash). However, this shouldn't be a problem, as AWK is a standard POSIX command that is most likely shipped by default with your operating system.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {return_code=(-1.2345 == -1.2345) ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
$ echo $?
0
$ awk 'BEGIN {return_code=(-1.2345 >= -1.2345) ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
$ echo $?
0
$ awk 'BEGIN {return_code=(-1.2345 < -1.2345) ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
$ echo $?
1
$ awk 'BEGIN {return_code=(-1.2345 < 2) ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
$ echo $?
0
$ awk 'BEGIN {return_code=(-1.2345 > 2) ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
$ echo $?
```

To make it shorter for use, use this function:

```
compare_nums()
{
   # Function to compare two numbers (float or integers) by using AWK.
   # The function will not print anything, but it will return 0 (if the comparison is true) or 1
   # (if the comparison is false) exit codes, so it can be used directly in shell one liners.
   #############
   ### Usage ###
   ### Note that you have to enclose the comparison operator in quotes.
   #############
   # compare_nums 1 ">" 2 # returns false
   # compare_nums 1.23 "<=" 2 # returns true
   # compare_nums -1.238 "<=" -2 # returns false
   #############################################
   num1=$1
   op=$2
   num2=$3
   E_BADARGS=65

   # Make sure that the provided numbers are actually numbers.
   if ! [[ $num1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then >&2 echo "$num1 is not a number"; return $E_BADARGS; fi
   if ! [[ $num2 =~ ^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then >&2 echo "$num2 is not a number"; return $E_BADARGS; fi

   # If you want to print the exit code as well (instead of only returning it), uncomment
   # the awk line below and comment the uncommented one which is two lines below.
   #awk 'BEGIN {print return_code=('$num1' '$op' '$num2') ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
   awk 'BEGIN {return_code=('$num1' '$op' '$num2') ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}'
   return_code=$?
   return $return_code
}

$ compare_nums -1.2345 ">=" -1.2345 && echo true || echo false
true
$ compare_nums -1.2345 ">=" 23 && echo true || echo false
false
```

Comment: I'm working with large numbers and `bash` fails to compare them properly (try `if (( 18446744073692774399 < 8589934592 )); then echo 'integer overflow'; fi`). `awk` works like a charm (`if awk "BEGIN {return_code=(18446744073692774399 > 8589934592) ? 0 : 1; exit} END {exit return_code}"; then echo 'no integer overflow'; fi`).

Answer (score 8):

If you have floats, you can write a function and then use that. For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

function float_gt() {
    perl -e "{if($1>$2){print 1} else {print 0}}"
}

x=3.14
y=5.20
if [ $(float_gt $x $y) == 1 ] ; then
    echo "do stuff with x"
else
    echo "do stuff with y"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using a small function to convert version strings to plain integer values that can be compared:

```
function versionToInt() {
  local IFS=.
  parts=($1)
  let val=1000000*parts[0]+1000*parts[1]+parts[2]
  echo $val
}
```

This makes two important assumptions:

1. The input is a "[normal SemVer string](http://semver.org/)"
2. Each part is between 0-999

For example

```
versionToInt 12.34.56  # --> 12034056
versionToInt 1.2.3     # -->  1002003
```

Example testing whether `npm` command meets the minimum requirement...

```
NPM_ACTUAL=$(versionToInt $(npm --version))  # Capture npm version
NPM_REQUIRED=$(versionToInt 4.3.0)           # Desired version
if [ $NPM_ACTUAL \< $NPM_REQUIRED ]; then
  echo "Please update to npm@latest"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: with 'sort -V' you can sort version numbers and then decide what to do then. You can write a compare function like this:
    function version_lt() {  test "$(printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort -V | head -n 1)" == "$1"; }
and use it like this:
    if version_lt $v1 $v2; then ...

Comment: What if the version string numbers have leading zeros? Will they be interpreted as octal numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to all the above answers:

If you have more than one expression in single if statement, you can do something like this:

```
if (( $a % 2 == 0 )) && (( $b % 2 != 0));
  then
  echo "What you want to do"
fi
```

Hope this helps!