# Unix shell command for uptime monitoring

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

apologies, I'm not a Unix guy, Windows and Powershell is more my area. I need to check the uptime on Linux servers using a shell command that can be invoked from SCOM.

I have been able to get the uptime in seconds back into SCOM using...

```
cat /proc/uptime | gawk -f ' ' '{print $1}'
```

However, SCOM does not pick this up as numerical, I think it's treating the returned output as a string.

I'd like a shell command that returns a 0 or 1 if the number of seconds is less than one day (86400).

I've been experimenting with [test -gt] but can't seem to get it working?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing numbers in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
cat /proc/uptime | gawk '{print ($1>86400)?1:0;}'
```

Comment: And if you really want "a shell command that _returns_ a 0 or 1" as an return value and not just prints it out, replace the `print` with `exit`.