# Bash MySQL query

Tags: mysql, bash, scripting

I'm trying to run a query against MySQL 5.6.35 in bash, and have it exit 0 if the value is greater than or equal to 14. I can get it to show the results I would expect, but not exit 0.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="SELECT count(*) FROM weekly WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"
mysql -u root -sN weekly_db -e "$query";

if test $query -ge 14 ; then
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
else
  echo "CRITICAL"
  exit 2
fi
```

Here is the bash script executed:

```
~# ./check.sh
39
./check.sh: line 6: test: too many arguments
CRITICAL
```

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**

Here is how I went about this thanks for codeforester's help

```
#!/bin/bash

query="SELECT count(*) FROM weekly WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"
OUTPUT=$(mysql -u root sN weekly_db -e "$query";)

if ((OUTPUT >= 14)) ; then
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
else
  echo "CRITICAL"
  exit 2
fi
```

Output:

```
~# ./check.sh
OK
```

Comment: Why would `$query` magically `-ge 14`? It's a SQL string.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, maybe i need to set a different variable on line 4.

Comment: As a note, `bash` is really the worst possible way to get data out of MySQL. If you can use Python, Ruby, Perl, Node.js, *anything* with a native MySQL driver you'll be far better off. Writing a simple wrapper script and mapping your result to an exit status code so `bash` can interpret it is pretty easy.

Comment: I understand, I need this to exit 0 for a quick custom nagios check. I know there are lots of different tools for that, but I feel this should also be easy. I just can't get bash to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Like I said, `bash` is really the worst possible tool for this since it doesn't understand MySQL at all. You *can* do this with a lot of `sed`, `awk` and other random duct tape, but you really don't want to. This is like four lines in any common scripting language where you can install a MySQL driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the `too many arguments` error because unquoted `$query` evaluates to many words that confuses `test`.  I am sure your intention is not to test the query, but the query results.  So, you need to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to capture the output of MySQL:

```
query_output=$(mysql -u root -sN weekly_db -e "$query")
```

and then test it with `(( ... ))` which is more appropriate for numeric logic:

```
if ((query_output >= 14)); then
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
else
  echo "CRITICAL"
  exit 2
fi
```

In case MySQL fails (connectivity or query issues), the query output would be empty and your logic will still work - the `if` condition will evaluate to false and `else` part would get executed.  I guess that's what you want.

---

See also:

- [Comparing numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash)

Comment: First off, thanks! You are correct I just want to test the results of the query. I tried this, but I'm getting a ton of mysql config output when running the command and it ends up critical. 

:~# ./check.sh
./check.sh: line 6: ((: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6
....
CRITICAL

Comment: okay, you led me to the correct answer. I'll update the original question. thanks again.