# Why does this if statement get evaluated to true in bash?

Tags: bash

```
# prints "here" when run in bash
if [[ ((9 > 220)) ]]; then echo "here"; fi
```

I'm confused why the above if statement gets evaluated to true.  Wouldn't `((9 > 220))` evaluate to false which would make the if statement false?
The code below behaves as expected.  I'm confused why using the double parentheses in a double brackets "if" isn't working above though.

```
# doesn't print anything
if ((9 > 220)); then echo "here"; fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between those two [compound commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands) inside a conditional construct.

### `[[ expression ]]` compound command

In your first example you're using the `[[ expression ]]` command:

```
if [[ ((9 > 220)) ]]; then echo "here"; fi
```

where **parenthesis are treated merely as grouping operators**, used to override the normal precedence of other operators (like `!`, `&&`, `||`, `>`, `-gt`, `-e`, etc.). The `>` operator in this case is a lexicographic greater than.

This is nicely described in `man bash`:

> `[[ expression ]]`
>
> Return  a  status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.  Expressions are composed of the primaries described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS.  Word splitting  and  pathname  expansion
>   are  not  performed  on the words between the [[ and ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution, and quote removal are performed.  Conditional  operators such as `-f` must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries.
>
> When used with `[[`, the `<` and `>` operators **sort lexicographically** using the current locale.

So, to compare integers in the `[[` compound command, you can use the [conditional expression operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), the same one used by `test` and `[` commands. For example like this:

```
if [[ 9 -gt 220 ]]; then echo "here"; fi
```

The result is the same like when the `-gt` operator is grouped with parenthesis:

```
if [[ ((9 -gt 220)) ]]; then echo "here"; fi
```

Alternatively, you can use the [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion-1) and exploit the fact that the boolean results are represented as `"0"` or `"1"`:

```
if [[ $((9 > 200)) == 1 ]]; then echo "here"; fi
```

### `(( expression ))` compound command

In your second example, you're using the `(( expression ))` command:

```
if ((9 > 220)); then echo "here"; fi
```

where the `expression` is evaluated according to the rules of the [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic). The `man bash` says:

> `((expression))`
>
> The  expression  is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly  equivalent
>   to `let "expression"`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It is because using double brackets makes it a *lexicographical comparison*. That means that it checks for which sequence is longer, like sorting alphabetically. More information about lexicographical comparisons [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/)

Comment: So the double hard brackets change the behavior of the nested double parentheses (which would normally use the arithmetic context)?

Comment: Or actually I see that if [[ 0 ]] evaluates to true so I'm guessing the arithmetic context is still behaving as expected but it's the double hard brackets that are making if [[ 0 ]] evaluate to true.

Comment: That is the case, yes. Bash expressions are evaluated differently. Interesting indeed

Comment: And to expand on this answer, because we are inside double brackets, the parentheses are just for grouping conditional expressions -- they do not introduce an arithmetic context at all. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs, scroll down for the `[[ ... ]]` part, then scroll down further for `( expression )`

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `[[ ]]`, the parentheses don't trigger an arithmetic context, they're interpreted purely for grouping/precedence<sup>1</sup>. All of these are equivalent:

```
$ [[ 0 < 1 ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ (0 < 1) ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ ((0 < 1)) ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ (((0 < 1))) ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ ((((0 < 1)))) ]] && echo yes
yes
```

If we have unbalanced parentheses, Bash complains about that:

```
$ [[ ((((0 < 1))) ]] && echo yes
bash: unexpected token `]]', expected `)'
bash: syntax error near `]]'
```

This all being said, `<` and `>` within `[[ ]]` are for lexicographical *string comparison*, so the statement above just checks if `0` is lexicographically sorted before `1` (it is).

Observe:

```
$ [[ 11 < 2 ]] && echo yes
yes
```

To compare numbers, you have to use `-gt`, `-lt`, `-ge`, `-le`, `eq`, `ne` instead of `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `=`, `!=`:

```
$ [[ 11 -lt 2 ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Since you're already using `(( ))`, you could use just that for comparing numbers:

```
$ (( 11 < 2 )) && echo yes || echo no
no
```

This is the simplest and clearest method in my opinion, if you know you have Bash at your disposal.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [the manual about `[[ ]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b):

> Expressions may be combined using the following operators, listed in
>   decreasing order of precedence:
>
> `( expression )`
>   Returns the value of *`expression`*. This may be used to override the normal precedence of operators.

Hat tip to glenn jackman for pointing to the manual in his comment to another answer.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm going to start just using if (( )); for all my if statements instead of double hard brackets.  I like that the > and < symbols actually compare variables as integers and that you can also do && and || within the arithmetic context.

Answer (score -1):

The double parentheses is an arithmetic context. If you use the brackets, you have to use `-lt` for less than and `-gt` for greater than. See [Comparing numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash).

Comment: Are you not supposed to use double parentheses within double hard brackets in bash? Shouldn't the ((9 > 220) evaluate first?  I know you're allowed to use the > symbol to compare integers in the arithmetic context.

Comment: No. You use double parentheses or double brackets, not both.