# Comparing numbers in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I wrote this script to compare 2 numbers in bash but it gives me wrong answers for some numbers.
like if I give it 2&2 for input , it gives me "X is greater than Y"

```
#!/bin/bash 
read num1
read num2
if [ $num1 > $num2 ]
    then 
        echo "X is greater than Y"
elif [ $num1 < $num2 ]
    then 
        echo "X is less than Y"
elif [ $num1 = $num2 ]
    then 
        echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

Comment: For comparing numbers, use `-gt` operator for `>`, `-lt` for `<` and `-eq` for `=`

Comment: @anubhava yet it gives wrong answer for input " 2 and 3"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668556/608639).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with bash arithmetic contexts:

```
#!/bin/bash 
read num1
read num2
if (( num1 > num2 ))
    then 
        echo "X is greater than Y"
elif (( num1 < num2 ))
    then 
        echo "X is less than Y"
elif (( num1 == num2 ))
    then 
        echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
cmp() {
    num1="$1"
    num2="$2"

    if [ $num1 -gt $num2 ]
        then 
            echo "X is greater than Y"
    elif [ $num1 -lt $num2 ]
        then 
            echo "X is less than Y"
    elif [ $num1 -eq $num2 ]
        then 
            echo "X is equal to Y"
    fi
}
```

Then see the results:

```
cmp 2 3
X is less than Y

cmp 2 2
X is equal to Y

cmp 2 1
X is greater than Y
```

Since you're using `bash`, I suggest you to use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

To make as few changes as possible double the brackets - to enter `'double bracket'` mode (is only valid in bash/zsh not in Bourne shell).

If you want to be compatible with sh you can stay in `'single bracket'` mode but you need to replace all operators.

In `'single bracket'` mode operators like `'<','>', '='` are used only to compare strings. To compare numbers in `'single bracket'` mode you need to use `'-gt'`, `'-lt'`, `'-eq'`

```
#!/bin/bash 
read num1
read num2
if [[ $num1 > $num2 ]]
    then 
        echo "X is greater than Y"
elif [[ $num1 < $num2 ]]
    then 
        echo "X is less than Y"
elif [[ $num1 = $num2 ]]
    then 
        echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

Comment: I think you should use a single '[' in bash. And also use -gt. , otherwise this will give the wrong output in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo hi enter first  number
read num1 

echo hi again enter second number
read num2

if [ "$num1" -gt "$num2" ]
then
  echo $num1 is greater than $num2
elif [ "$num2" -gt "$num1" ]
then
  echo $num2 is greater than $num1
else
  echo $num1 is equal to $num2
fi
```

(Please note : we will use -gt operator for > , -lt for < , == for = )

Comment: Regarding last line: no, you use `-eq` for numeric equality in `[ ... ]` ,not `==`.