# Loop BASH with counter in one line

Tags: bash, loops

I wait program finish and print nothing; but this intro in loop:

```
while [ 0 > 0 ]; do echo 1; done
```

logically 0 no't is > to 0...
why get loop?

How I can get nothing by screen? and program finish fine?

After of my progam "nothing to do":

```
while [ 0 > 0 ]; do echo 1; done
```

I like in one line:

```
q = 0; while [ q < 9 ]; q ++; do echo q; done
```

it´s possible in one line?

Thanks

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668580/5267751).

Comment: Why are you redirecting to a file called `0`?

Answer (score 13):

```
q = 0; while [ q < 9 ]; q ++; do echo q; done
```

Just 5 errors in one line.

- q=0 may not have white space around the assignment operator
- q ++ has to be in double round parens
- q < 9 has to be -lt (less than)
- in single brackets [ $q -lt 9 ] q needs to be $q
- the do should follow the while

Possible solution:

```
q=0; while [[ q -lt 3 ]]; do ((q++)); echo $q; done
1
2
3
```

echoing values can be done with

```
echo {1..9}
```

too, but is not flexible, so you can't use variable expansion inside, like  `echo {1..$n}`. The canonical way of doing initialization, increment and threshold check, is a for loop:

```
 for (( q=1; q < 4; ++q)); do  echo $q ; done
```

There is the external program seq, which is not so much recommended, for that reason:

```
seq 1 3
```

First question:

```
while [ 0 > 0 ]; do echo 1; done
```

Look for a file 0 where you used file redirection (instead of -gt), like in echo `foo > 0.file`.

Instead of

```
while [ 0 -gt 0 ]; do echo 1; done
```

because it does nothing. It doesn't wait for anything. Either your program is sequential, then it is finished at that point anyhow. Or there is a program/command in the background running, which doesn't care about this anti loop anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, use
    for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done

Also refer to [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: thanks; some help about/around my first Q? (((0 no't is > to 0... why get loop? )))