# How can I check if a variable that need to contain a number has been set?

Tags: bash

Given the following code:

```
Max=
if [[ something exists.. ]]; then
     Max=2
// .. more code that can changes the value of Max
fi
// HERE
```

How can I check at "HERE" if Max is equal to some number (setted)?

Answer (score 0):

Cool !

Max is set by default to an empty value, that when used in an arithmetic context, returns zero. For example:

Try running `echo $(( definitelyNotAGivenName))` it comes out as zero, cool!

You can use the round brackets for arithmetic comparing - see more [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash)

Comment: I don't know which shell you are using but `bash` does definitely not default vars to zero.

Comment: @keithpjolley, in an arithmetic context it does, as an empty string (the result of expanding an unset variable) is treated as having a zero value in such a context (when unquoted -- `$(( $empty ))` evaluates to 0, `$(( "$empty" ))` is an error).

Comment: Fixed the phrasing for ya

Comment: Neat! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -z "$Max" ]
then
  echo "Max: not set"
else if [ $Max -eq some_number ]
then
  echo "Max is equal to some number"
else
  echo "Max is set but not equal to some number"
fi
```

or

```
if [ -n "$Max" -a "$Max" = "some_number" ]
...
```

Notice that the second example is doing a string comparison which can solve some headaches but may hurt the sensibilities of purists.

Comment: Note that `-a` is marked obsolescent in the POSIX test standard; see the `OB` markers in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Also, `=` is a string comparator, perhaps you want `-eq`. Is it okay for `5` to be different from `05`?

Comment: I found the purist. :)

Comment: @ghoti - `=` is on purpose to guard against something like `Max=five`. I  assumed `some_number` is hardcoded into the script, not user input.

Comment: Sometimes it matters -- `test` uses that allow logical ANDs, ORs and parenthesis to control order-of-operations are obsolescent for good reason. Consider if `a='('` and `b=')'`; is `[ "$a" = "$b" ]` asking if `(` and `)` are the same character (false!), or is it a grouping operation testing whether `=` is a non-empty string (true!)? That particular corner case is a simple one, for ease of explanation, but nastier variants exist. `[[ ]]` doesn't have the problem -- being syntax, it knows which words were expanded from variables and which were part of the expression.