# bash script: getting idle time and compare it

Tags: bash, sh, idle-processing

Why is the if-compression not comparing the value?

```
idle_time=exec sudo -u home xprintidle

if [ "$idle_time" -ge 6000 ]
  then
  echo "hi"
fi
```

it is not working like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I changed to line which you use to execute xprintidle as a different user.
After that I adjusted the if clause, since there was an error as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
# actually assign the variable
idle_time=$(idle_time=exec sudo -u home xprintidle)
# adapted if clause to actually match (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash) 
if [ "$idle_time" -gt "6000" ]; then
    echo "hi"
fi
```