# Trying to get a regex value for > 30,000

Tags: ruby, regex, sensu

I'm using this sensu plugin https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-process-checks/blob/master/bin/check-cmd.rb

to run

```
sudo lsof | grep couchbase | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

I'm trying to come up with a regex for the output. I want it to alert if the value is over 30,000 connections.

What would be the regex I can use?

Comment: That's not what regex is for, just [compare the two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash).

Comment: Thank you.. decided to create a bash script instead.. agreed on use of regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 30000 = `3\d{3}[1-9]|[4-9]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{5,17}|[1-8]\d{18}|9\d{18,}`

Add boundary conditions where needed.