# Variable comparison and pattern replacement

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed

I am trying to create a bash script that uses the sed command to replace a pattern by a variable that contains a string or put a space if there is nothing in the variable. I cannot find the good way to write it and make it work. Here is the part where I have issues:

```
a_flag=$(echo $a | wc -w)

if  [[ $a_flag = 0 ]]; then
    sed -i -e 's/#b/\\hspace{2cm}/g' source.tex
else
    sed -i -e "s/#b/$a/g" source.tex
fi
```

When running this, the condition is always false. I tried [] or (()) for the if statement but I just can't find a way to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash)

Comment: Replace your if statement by   if  [[ "$a_flag" -eq "0" ]];

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried the two solutions of the accepted answer and it still doesn't work. I tried (( a_flag = 0)) and [ "$a_flag" -eq "0"]

Comment: `sed -i -e "s/#b/${a:-\\\\hspace{2cm}/g" source.tex`. Done.

Comment: We are slightly in the dark here because it's unclear what exactly `$a` contains. I guess it's never completely empty, like @chepner assumes.

Comment: When `a` is empty, `a_flag` is not the literal string `0`; it's a `0` with a lot of leading whitespace. Use `-eq` to test numerically.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single parameter expansion here, to replace the expansion of `$a` with `\hspace{2cm}` if the expansion is empty.

```
sed -i -e "s/#b/${a:-\\\\hspace{2cm}}/g" source.tex
```

You need a stack of `\` because there are two rounds of escaping involved. First, the shell itself reduces each `\\` to a single literal backslash. Then `sed` *also* reduces each pair of `\\` to a single literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of occurrences of someething seems like a very roundabout way to approach this anyway.

```
case $a in
   *[A-Za-z0-9_]*) x='\\hspace{2cm}';;
   *)              x=$a;;
esac
sed -i "s/#b/$x/g" source.tex
```

Comment: I tried this and this time it prints the \hspace but not the content of a:
`case $a in
  *[A-Za-z0-9_]*) sed -i -e 's/#b/\\hspace{2cm}/g' source.tex;;
  *)              sed -i -e "s/#b/$a/g" source.tex;;
 esac`