# How do i output the result of my command in this script?

Tags: bash, echo, rhel7

```
if [ "$(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)" == "644" ]
then
  echo "Is there a vulnerability: No, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is correct."
else
  echo "Is there a vulnerability: Yes, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is incorrect. echo awk -F: $(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)"
fi
```

This is an audit script i am working on, and I would like to output the current Permissions of the /etc/crontab file, if it is not equals to chmod 644. I've tried many methods to no avail. I am doing this in a RHEL 7 server if it matters.

Comment: Where exactly did you notice a problem?

Comment: `echo "Is there a vulnerability: Yes, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is incorrect. echo awk -F: $(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)"`. Should it be `echo "Is there a vulnerability: Yes, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is incorrect : $(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)"` ? (without `awk -F:`)

Comment: The code looks fine and works for me. Beside this you should considered using the recommended arithmetic context in `Bash`: `if (( "$(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)" == 644 )); then echo "Vulnerability"; fi`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash.

Comment: Can you share the output of `stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab`  ? Given that this is audit script, might be that the file has more restricted permission than 0644, which should be OK for the audit purpose (e.g., 0600, or even 0400).

Answer (score 1):

This should be the most correct way to do what you want

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab) == 644 ))
then
  echo "Is there a vulnerability: No, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is correct."
else
  echo "Is there a vulnerability: Yes, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is incorrect: $(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)"
fi
```

Comment: That's what I wrote in my comment above, though.

Comment: Your comment pointed out the numeric compare and it's right, another comment fixed the awk command substitution, also right. This is the whole solution, with the correct syntax, not just one part

Answer (score 0):

When you compare numbers in bash you should use `-eq` instead of `==`. So your `if` from this:

```
if [ "$(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)" == "644" ]
```

must be

```
if [ "$(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)" -eq "644" ]
```

And in this line

```
 echo "Is there a vulnerability: Yes, Permission set on /etc/crontab file is incorrect. echo awk -F: $(stat -c "%a" /etc/crontab)"
```

you should remove quotes around `%a`

Comment: Does this answer solve the problem of the questioner?

Comment: @Cyrus, IMO yes.

Comment: I'd say maybe, as I pointed out both methods work for me on my two test boxes.