# Bash - Comparsion of two variables not working as intended

Tags: bash, shell

we are running a bash script on a unix-server to check a value against a treshold and sent the result to a monitoring system via snmp.
The goal is to sent a defined alarmtext to the monitoring infrastructure if the value is greater than the defined treshold.

When running a debug of this script everything works fine and the correct alarmtext is displayed via echo on the cli.

Scriptsnippet:

```
## LOGIC ##
if [[ ${ActiveRecipientsQueue} -gt ${Threshold} ]]; then
        echo "$AlarmText";
        exit 1;
else
        echo "$NoAlarmText";
        exit 0;
fi
```

Result of debug - scenario threshold reached:

```
+ [[ 15 -gt 5 ]]
+ echo 'Treshsold was reached!'
Treshsold was reached!
+ exit 1
```

Result of debug - scenario everything ok:

```
+ [[ 15 -gt 500 ]]
+ echo 'Everything is fine'
Everything is fine
+ exit 0
```

The issue is now that on the monitoring infrastructure everytime the "everything ok" message is displayed, no matter if the threshold was reached or not.

I am still confused about this and can't find any logical explanation for this.

May you can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use only one bracket! `[ $a -gt $b ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/comparing-numbers-in-bash

Comment: Are you sure the monitoring infrastructure runs the same version of the script? Can you add some debugging into it, at least show the values being compared?

Comment: Are you sure that it's being run by the same shell in both environments?  Perhaps stick to standard (POSIX) shell features? i.e. `[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]`.  BTW, you misspelt *threshold*.

Comment: To add to Toby Speight's comment, if your monitoring infrastructure is using some other POSIX shell rather than `bash`, `[[` is not recognized as a valid command, leading to a failure that your script interprets as a comparison that evaluates to false. Using `[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]`, as suggested by F. Hauri, should work.

Comment: @smuellert : To catch what chepner suspected: Did you verify that nothing is written on STDERR? Also, to debug the problem, I would include the values of `ActiveRecipientsQueue`, `Threshold` and `BASH_VERSION` into the ok-message. The latter also helps to verify that you are indeed running bash.