# Remove double prefix from filenames

Tags: bash, duplicates, rename, move

I have files nested in folders. In case the filename starts with a string that is repeated twice, I would like to change the filename to a name such that this string appears only once.

For example:

- Rename "Dirty Projectors - Dirty Projectors - Search For Life.mp3"
  to "Dirty Projectors - Search For Life.mp3"
- Rename "Eefje de Visser - Eefje de Visser - Bitterzoet.mp3" to "Eefje de Visser - Bitterzoet.mp3"
- Keep "Feng Suave - Maybe Another Time.mp3" as it is.

How can I do this using command-line in Linux?

Comment: If you have the Perl `rename` command, you can use a regular expression that matches a string followed by the same string, by using back-references.

Comment: `s/^(.*)\1/\1/` will replace a duplicate string at the beginning of a filename.

Comment: Note that this means that if the filename begins with `ee` it will change to `e`. If you want the match to end with `-` you need to be more specific.

Comment: @Barmar, do you mean something like `perl-rename 's/^(.*)\\1/\\1/' *.mp3`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined the regex of @Barmar and the shell script of @U880D to remove any duplicate prefix in the filenames recursively. There was a problem with using `find` and `perl-rename`, so I had to do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar;
for DIR in ${PWD}/**/; do
    cd "${DIR}"
    for FILENAME in *.mp3 ; do
        NEWFILENAME=$(echo "${FILENAME}" | perl -pe 's/^(.*)\1/\1/')
        if [ "${FILENAME}" != "${NEWFILENAME}" ] ; then
            mv "${FILENAME}" "${NEWFILENAME}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I do this using command-line in Linux?*

After some research it seems to be a bit more complex. Therefore it will probably end up in a script.

**`renameMusic.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY=$1
cd ${DIRECTORY}
echo "Normalize filenames in $(pwd)"

for FILENAME in *; do
  echo
  echo "Checking file ${FILENAME}"

  # Count number of dash (-)
  NUMBER=$(grep -o '-' <<< ${FILENAME} | wc -l)
  echo "Found ${NUMBER} of dash (-)"
  
  # Check if the artist name seems to be there twice
  if [[ "${NUMBER}" -eq 2 ]]; then
    # If so, remove the double part
    NEWFILENAME=$(echo "${FILENAME}" | cut -d "-" -f 2- | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
    echo "Going to move to new name ${NEWFILENAME}"

    # mv ${FILENAME} ${NEWFILENAME}

  fi

done
```

**Thanks to**

- [Looping through `ls` results in Bash shell script](https://superuser.com/questions/31464/)
- [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/)
- [Count total number of occurrences using `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/)
- [Comparing numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/)
- [How to trim whitespace from a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/h)
- [Whats the difference between `rename` and `mv`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510553/)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/)

Comment: Please take note that I've commented out the renaming part so that it will be possible to have a dry run. I my test setup and test run it worked well. Since you have mentioned that "_I have files nested in folders._", I will leave that part to you.

Comment: Thank you, this works in case I put quotes around the arguments of the mv command.

Comment: You should always quote your variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @U880D, Actually It does not work in case the folder name contains a dash. I have tried to write `find -name "*.mp3"  -type f -printf '%P\n' | xargs perl-rename 's/^(.*)\1/\1/'` but it does not change the names. It only works when I use it without the find.

Comment: Thanks for the hint [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/). I'll put it into the credits.

Comment: @sryscad, you may take advantage from [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/). So by enhancing the script with `# Make sure globstar is enabled
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.mp3; do # Whitespace-safe and recursive` 
it would work. At least it did in my test setup.