# Operand expected (error token is "/ur/sbin/no login >= 1000 ")

Tags: shell, for-loop, syntax-error

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function userList() {
for line in $(cat /etc/passwd)
do
    USER=$(echo $line | cut -d":" -f1)
    USERID=$(echo $line | cut -d":" -f3)
    if (( $USERID >= 1000 ))
        then
                echo $USER
        fi
done
}
```

I want it to show all the users of the system but every time I call the function in the terminal it throws the names of the users but also this errors:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ur/sbin/no login >= 1000 ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare numbers in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/how-can-i-compare-numbers-in-bash)

Comment: @MartinZeitler What's the relevance? The OP is using `(( ))` correctly.

Comment: Also `/ur/sbin/no login` appears to be invalid. Comparing string to number... which means `$USERID` is not being assigned properly. `awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd` is way simpler / easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for line in $(cat /etc/passwd)
> ```

That's not iterating over lines in the file, but over *words* in the file, where a word is separated by a space *or* tab *or* newline. When the line contains two words, then `$line` becomes something else, then `echo $line | cut -d":" -f3` may not be a number. For example on this line:

```
name:password:UID:GID:A comment:directory:shell
```

Then `$line` will be equal to `name:password:UID:GID:A` on first loop iteration, than to `comment:directory:shell` on second loop iteration. On the second time, your script give an error - `shell` is not a number.

Check your script will shellcheck. Quote variable expansions. Use `while IFS= read- r` to read a file line by line, or in this case `while IFS=: read -r` to read field by field. Consider reading a tutorial on how to do basic shell scripting, like reading a file line by line. You may read about https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . And, consider writing it in awk, it will be just `awk -F: '$3>=1000{print $1}'`.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly thank you very much. I will study the info you provided me tought.