# Comparing value string and fixed value

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote small script under Debian Linux 11 that should check how many instances of application is currently running and what is power usage of GPU cards.
I save it under name test , and she is started every time I access instance over SSH

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
a=$(nvidia-smi -q -i 0 | grep "Power Draw" | cut -c45-50) 
b=$(nvidia-smi -q -i 1 | grep "Power Draw" | cut -c45-50) 
c=$(nvidia-smi -q -i 2 | grep "Power Draw" | cut -c45-50) 
d=$(nvidia-smi -q -i 3 | grep "Power Draw" | cut -c45-50) 
zet=$( echo "$a" + "$b" + "$c" + "$d"  | bc -l )
echo "SYSTEM DRAW:" "$zet"
if [ "${zet}" -gt 150 ]; then          
echo WARRNING - SYSTEM DRAW LOW                                       
else
echo OK  
fi
sleep 8
exit
```

Comment: `power=$150` , but what is the value of variable `$150` ? I do not see it defined?

Comment: There's a whole lot wrong with your script, try putting it through [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net), but also visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/how-can-i-compare-numbers-in-bash

Comment: And you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the section  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: Also, if you really have named your script `test` avoid a whole bunch of mysterious errors by renaming it `mytest` or something else. `test` is a standard part of all (sh, bash, ksh, zsh) shell "languages" and having another command available that responds to `"test"` will not be fun to debug. Good luck!

Comment: `if [ "$total" -gt "$power" ] ...` as one of possible variants.

Comment: `>` is the redirection operator. `[ foo > bar ]` is equilvalent to `test foo > bar` and creates an empty file named `5`.  For string comparision use `[ foo '>' bar ]`. For numerical (integer) comparision use `-gt` instead of `'>'`. See _man test_ for the details.

Comment: `$150` is interpreted as `${1}50`, i.e. the first positional parameter, with the string `50` appended. I don't know what you want to do here. `${150}` would fetch the 150th positional parameter, but I doubt that this is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

All I need to add is this line
x=${x%.*}
That convert decimal number in number without decimals and script works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `set -x` right before the part you want to debug, which will show you a debug of what is happening in bash. and stop it by inserting after that `set +x`

like:

```
set -x
power=$150
echo "SYSTEM DRAW :" $total
if [ $total \> $power ] ; then # escape > otherwise it redirects output
```

I do not think you are setting the value of `$150`

The script might be failing if one of the compared values is not set.. so you should initialize your variables to be let' say equal to `0` as a default at the beginning of your script, or via bash

like:

```
power=${150:-10} # if $150 does not have a value or empty, the default value of $power will be set to `10`
```

Comment: He's not comparing anything ... he's executing `$total` and redirecting its output to the content of `$power` ...

Comment: Better: but what he **really** wants is `[ "$total" -gt "$power" ]` ... (provided they're integer values).

Comment: [ "$total" -gt "$power" ] - I also got error - illegal number

Comment: did you run your script with `-x` as explained above to confirm `$power` actually hods a value and is not empty? If one of the sides is empty of course you cannot compare.

Answer (score 0):

So many possible issues but you can compare possibly decimal values using `bc`:

```
if [ "$(echo "$total > $power" | bc)" = 1 ]; then
```

Comment: This seems like massive overkill, executing a separate process and capturing its output, when the shell can do this directly.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Indeed. Unfortunately the common shell doesn't support decimals. Not even Bash. Not sure about Zsh.

Comment: bash certainly does with `((` -- and since the question is marked `linux`, one can assume bash.

Comment: Also I chose not to presume he's using / want to use Bash, even with the likely availability. With all those other subshell statements, a subshell command like this isn't an immediate worry.

Comment: @ChrisDodd No, a decimal will cause invalid arithmetic error. With Bash best you can only do is use a here document instead of a pipe and an echo. And use `[[ ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments recommend, use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), however, I think your intention is not what you wrote.

Try this, create a script (i.e. `myscripy`)

```
#! /bin/bash

power=$150
echo "power=$power"
```

then run it

```
./myscript abc
```

and prints

```
power=abc50
```

which is probably very different than what you expect.

That is because `power` will take the first argument's value (`$1`) and append `50`.

If you wanted argument number `150` (*also very unlikely*), you should write

```
power=${150}
```

but if you want just the number

```
power=150
```

#### edit

based on the comment, use

```
zet=$(bc <<<"$a+$b+$c+$d")
```

to calculate `zet` if the values are floating points.

For the comparison use

```
if [ "$(bc <<<"$zet>150")" == 1 ]; then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: Ok , now I do check as you suggested and there is no error now. But  when I access via SSH I got this error

u8: 9: [: Illegal number: 301.63

Comment: Only integer math is supported in shell

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `[` (and `[[`) do *string* comparisons, and you want a *numeric* comparison.  For that you want to use `((`, so something like

```
if (( $total > 150 )); then
    echo "WARNING..."
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

will work better.  Otherwise a total of `1000` would print ok, and `90` would give a warning.

Other problems:

- `$150` gives you the value of a variable called `150` -- you probably want to remove the `$`
- Outside of special forms like `[[` and `((`, a `>` will do an output redirection, rather than being a 'normal' argument to a command such as `[`.

Comment: AFIK, `(( .... ))` does not work in POSIX shells (though `$(( ... ))` does). Note that the question is tagged _shell_, which means that the OP is interested in a POSIX solution.